# How to compare data in each cell in columns using VBA, copy value of cells in next column and paste in different spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have an excel workbook with two sheets. Each has exactly the same format in terms of columns. The columns are 
ColA - ID
ColB - Desc/dept
ColC - Name

Sheet2 has all the information in all columns.
Sheet1 only has information in ColC.

I would like to write VBA code to compare the values in Column C for both sheets and if it matches (as they might not be in the same order or even the same number of records) then the code copies the ID and Desc from columns A and B of Sheet2(*forId*) into Columns A and B of sheet1(*1099(2)*). I wrote the following but it just runs and excel stops responding after I click on it. When I select to restart excel, nothing changed.

Thanks for your help.

```
Sub insertId()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim compRngI As Range, compRngO As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim x As Variant, y As Variant

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'setting sheet where id to be checked
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("forId")

'set sheet where id to be pasted
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1099(2)")

'Set ranges to be compared between sheets
    With wsI
         lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Set compRngI = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
    End With

    With wsO
        lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set compRngO = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
    End With

'compare cells in both columns C of each spreadsheet
    For Each x In compRngI
        For Each y In compRngO
            If x = y Then
                y.Offset(0, -2).Value = x.Offset(0, -2).Value
                y.Offset(0, -1).Value = x.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        Next y
    Next x


ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set compRngI = .Range("C:C")` Don't set it to the entire column? Find the last row and limit range to that.

Comment: As @findwindow stated, use one of the methods shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) to find the last used cell.  You are iterating the loop 1,000,000^2 times by looping through the entire column.  You could also use the `find` method or `autofilter` to cut down on the loops.

Comment: Thanks @scottCraner. I edit the portion of code as below but now no errors and nothing happens                                                                                       'Set ranges to be compared between sheets
        `With wsI
            lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set compRngI = .Range("C" & lastRow)
    End With
    
        With wsO
            lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set compRngO = .Range("C" & lastRow)
        End With`

Comment: Change your Original post by using the edit option and repost your code.  It is easier to read.

Comment: thanks @findwindow. made change but now no errors nor any results. it doesn't do anything when i click run.

Comment: this line `Set compRngI = .Range("C" & lastRow) ` should be `Set compRngI = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow) ` same with the second one.

Comment: @ScottCraner made the changes in original post. Please see above.

Comment: Scott's better than I. Just go with what he says.

Comment: did you see my last comment?

Comment: @findwindow not better, just wired different. There are time I miss the simplest things that I am amazed you find.

Comment: @ScottCraner better as in more practiced/knowledgeable =P

Comment: @ScottCraner I made the second change as suggested. (Will update original post to reflect same) Once again, there are no errors. The title bar of excel briefly says "running" and nothing changes.

Comment: @ScottCraner i was looking in the wrong sheet. I accidentally set the input values that were to be copied(x values) to the blank cells (y values). i switched the x and y around in the last block and it worked. (will update original post to reflect change) Thanks so much!

Comment: Couldn't you just do this using MATCH and INDEX formulas?

Comment: @CrazyHorse I don't know how to use those.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by using a `MATCH` and `INDEX` formula, and it'll run much faster than trying to do this with VBA.

The `MATCH` part returns a value's position in a range, and `INDEX` allows you to retrieve a value in a given position of a range. It's functionally similar to a `VLOOKUP` but allows you to return values to the left of the lookup column.

In your case, you want the following 2 formulas in columns A and B of your `1099(2)` sheet:

Column A (ID)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

Column B (Desc/dept)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

The `0` in the `MATCH` formula means it has to find an exact match, rather than the nearest value that is less than the value being looked up (in which case you'd put 1 here) or greater than (which would be -1).

Also, a rule of thumb with Excel is that you should always try to achieve things using the built in formulas before writing your own VBA code, as the built in formulas will always be a lot faster than VBA.

Comment: Formulas are faster if we are talking a small sample group, not if we are talking thousands of rows, then vba using arrays will be faster.  The more formulas the slower the calculation time.

Comment: Thank you for your help @crazyHorse. I was able to realize that excel has more formulae than I am aware of and I am currently able to use index.